# Is htmlspecialchars needed for inline ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, htmlspecialchars

I read the contents of a text file, use inline editor to edit then write back to same text file. Do I need to use htmlspecialchars? If I do, when? Displaying to html, writing back to the file or both?

Answer (score 2):

When you output to the edit page ( the one with ckeditor ) you use both stripslashes() and htmlspecialchars().

Comment: Hey! But when I use htmlspecialchars it shows all the HTML brackets and no HTML format. So at least I should not use that when display then.